# How i do autoexpand input, not textarea?

Tags: jquery, input, autoresize

Like this http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/
But not textarea, input. It's didn't work with input.For example:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='jss/jquery.autosize.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('.normal').autosize();
            });
        </script>
    <body>
        <textarea class='normal'></textarea>
    </body>
```

I need- the input of fixed width, height changes

```
<input class='normal'/>
```

Help pls

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ahaxe

Comment: Ah yes, the input of fixed width, height changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) DIV:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="normal"></div>
```

```css
.normal {
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 3px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4EX6/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can use:

> ```
>     $(".normal").bind("keydown", function () {
>         var charWidth = $(this).css("font-size").replace("px", "") * 0.5;
>         var newWidth = (($(this).val().length + 10) * charWidth);
>         var minWidth = 100;
>         var maxWidth = 1000;
>         if (newWidth > minWidth && newWidth < maxWidth) {
>             $(this).width(newWidth);
>         }
>     });
> ```

Factor of 0.5 used in calculating character width will depend on type of font you are using.
However 0.5, should be good enough for most of font types.

Specifying min and max width will ensure that width of control does not go out of bounds.